# How can I split a file in order to obtain parameters with shell?

Tags: linux, shell, file, split, parameters

I have a problem with a file, I need to divide each line of this and send them as parameters to another shell . The file contains the folowing lines

```
20191224900|1
20191230901|1
20200107905|1
2020020891|1
2020010984|1
```

For example, the first line has to be divided like this

```
19
12 
24 
900
```

the second line has to be divided like this

```
19 
12
30
901
```

For each loop these numbers have to be sent has parameters to another shell

Example:

```
another_shell $19 $12 $30 $901
```

But when I run a test, the only result I have is the file divided by columns, and I need apply the split for every line individually and send the parameters

```
while read line; 
do 
    echo "year"
    awk '{print substr($1,3,2)}'
    echo "month"
    awk '{print substr($1,5,2)}' 
    echo "day"
    awk '{print substr($1,7,2)}' 
    echo "store"
    sed 's/|1//' REPROCESO_VTA_20200107.txt | awk '{print substr($1,9,3)}'
done < REPROCESO_VTA_20200107.txt
```

Comment: Surely `another_shell $19 $12 $30 $901` is not right.  That's attempting to pass the current shell's positional parameters, including the 901st, which does not make much sense, especially in context.  Do you just mean `another_shell 19 12 30 901`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Without curly braces, it would be equivalent to `another_shell ${1}9 ${1}2 ${3}0 ${9}01`, which I also assume isn't the intention...

Comment: You're right, @BenjaminW., my bad.  And I rate that even less likely to be what the OP really wants.

Comment: The way you've constructed the while loop is wrong.  `while read line` will read 1 line of input.  `awk` will then consume the rest of the input.  Then `sed` will read the entire file.  Then `read` will try to read and fail, and the loop only goes through one iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code ...

> ```
> while read line; 
> do 
>     echo "year"
>     awk '{print substr($1,3,2)}'
>     echo "month"
>     awk '{print substr($1,5,2)}' 
>     echo "day"
>     awk '{print substr($1,7,2)}' 
>     echo "store"
>     sed 's/|1//' REPROCESO_VTA_20200107.txt | awk '{print substr($1,9,3)}'
> done < REPROCESO_VTA_20200107.txt
> ```

... you are telling `sed` to process the whole input file on every loop iteration.  That's entirely separate from the shell reading one line from the same file on every iteration via the `read` command.  Inasmuch as your intention seems to be merely to strip any trailing `|1` from each line, it's also pretty wasteful.  It's even more wasteful to pipe the result into a separate `awk` process, since

- you could have done with `sed` what you are doing with `awk`, and in that case skipped what you actually *are* doing with `sed` (or *vice versa*); and
- everything you're doing with both of those can easily be done directly in the shell, instead, without launching separate processes.

Furthermore, everything else you appear to be trying to do with `awk` *also* can be done in shell code, instead of launching whole separate processes for such minor tasks.

Consider this:

```
while read line; do

  # strip the shortest trailing substring matching the glob |*
  line=${line%|*}

  # split the string based on fixed field widths for all but the last field,
  # using the results as arguments to an execution of some_program.
  # The quoting may be overkill.  It is unnecessary when all lines of the
  # input comply with the specified format.
  some_program "${line:2:2}" "${line:4:2}" "${line:6:2}" "${line:8}"

done < REPROCESO_VTA_20200107.txt
```

Comment: I get this message when apply this solution  --> the specified substitution is not valid for this command , the shell in this enviroment is to old . I`m going to keep working . Thanks a lot

Comment: That seems unlikely to be related to the specific suggestion above, @CristopherVergara, but I cannot say anything more about that without knowing what version of the shell you are using.

Answer (score 0):

A terribly fragile idea: just add some whitespace. Assuming your `another_shell` is not actually a shell but merely some command, you could do something like:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh

cat << EOF |
20191224900|1
20191230901|1
20200107905|1
2020020891|1
2020010984|1
EOF
sed -E 's/(..)(..)(..)(..)([^|]*)/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 /' |
while read _ one two thre four _; do
        echo "$one" "$two" "$thre" "$four"
done
$ ./a.sh
19 12 24 900
19 12 30 901
20 01 07 905
20 02 08 91
20 01 09 84
```

Replace `echo` in the above with `another_shell` and you're done.